absolute positioned div should move down dynamically
absolutely positioned pink div (modal_container) needs to move down as new items are added to input_container. Pink one should stay just beneath input_container.
Tried somethings by setting bottom in modal_container, but could not create a dynamic behaviour.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My CSS Grid</title>
    <style>
      body {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: "Nunito Semibold";
        text-align: center;
      }
      .page {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-template-areas:
          "header header header"
          "aside comp main";
      }
      .page > * {
        background: #3bbced;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .header {
        grid-area: header;
      }
      .comp {
        grid-area: comp;
        position: relative;
      }
      .input_cell {
        display: grid;
        position: relative;
      }
      .input_container {
        flex: 1;
      }
      .modal_container {
        flex: 1;
        background-color: pink;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .input_item {
        background-color: aqua;
      }
      .selected_container {
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page">
      <div class="comp">
        <div class="input_cell">
          <div class="input_container">
            <div>Item 4</div>
            <div>Item 4</div>
            <div>Item 4</div>
            <input class="input_item" />
          </div>
          <div class="modal_container">
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 1</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
            <div>Item 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




bottom positions from the bottom, it specifies where the bottom edge of the element gets positioned. You want to position from the top instead - top: 100%, so that the top edge of the element, starts at the bottom edge of the relative container.

If I understand this correctly you want the pink element to move relative to the blue element. Can you not just move it so it's a sibling rather than a child of the blue box then position it relatively?

Have you used any js then please add.

@CBroe top:100%did it. Thanks a lot for all the answers
